# Placing plugin or action in submenu using PyQGIS or PyQT

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt, actions, menu

I am trying to place a plugin into a submenu of "Vector". In this case "Geoprocessing Tools".

When I use:

```
iface.addPluginToVectorMenu('Geoprocessing Tools',action)
```

or:

```
iface.addPluginToVectorMenu('&Geoprocessing Tools',action)
```

it creates a new and double submenu "Geoprocessing Tools" with the action placed only in the new one.
Do I miss some formatting rules or is it just not possible?

[image: double submenu]

Answer (score 4):

It can be improved (tests, search of the submenu text) but the code below will add your action in the right Geoprocessing Tools submenu :

```py
def add_plugin_to_geoprocessing_menu(action: QAction) -> bool:
    vector_menu = iface.vectorMenu()
    geoprocessing_action = [
        a for a in vector_menu.findChildren(QAction) if "Geoprocessing" in a.text()
    ][0]
    geoprocessing_menu = geoprocessing_action.menu()
    geoprocessing_menu.addAction(action)
    return True


add_plugin_to_geoprocessing_menu(action)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
It gives an error when starting QGis :

"a for a in vector_menu.findChildren(QAction) if "Geoprocessing" in a.text()][0]
             IndexError: list index out of range"

But when reloaded it adds to the right Submenu. I guess the vector menu isn't yet loaded when this plugin loads?

Comment: I think you're right. I didn't test the code inside a plugin. QGIS should load other plugins before its submenus (related to processing core plugins), so currently, I have no idea to achieve this for your plugin context.

Comment: That is probably also the reason the submenus doubles in the first place. Again thanks, learned a lot from it :)